# Bitcoin withdrawal from blockchain

Tags: blockchain.info, sell-bitcoins

Greeting of the Day,

hi , I'm from India and i have bitcoin balance in my blockchain account but i don't how i convert it into real cash and withdraw.

you are requested to kindly guide me and suggest me the way.

Awaiting for you reply.

Thanks & regards

Comment: The term for converting something other than cash into cash is "selling". What you want to do is *sell* your bitcoins.

Answer (score 0):

The process would be to deposit the bitcoins into a bitcoin exchange, sell them there, and withdraw your cash from exchange account to your bank account. but make sure the exchange must be able to send money to your bank.

Also you have one more option is "Bitcoin ATMs" but I think in we don't have any ATM machine.